# os.makedirs not working with tkinter? Not sure what's going wrong

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a program that generates images that are saved to a directory that is created everytime it runs. The program works fine when I run it through the command line but when I run it throuh a tkinter button, it doesn't seem to create the directory. The program also outputs a log file but that seems to work.  Apparently the code executes as I figured out by some old fashioned print statement debugging.  Any ideas on why this might be? Here is the function
:

```
def compareImages(self,img1, img2, image_name):
        diff = cv2.absdiff(img1, img2)
        mask = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        th = 1
        imask =  mask>th
    
        canvas = np.zeros_like(img2, np.uint8)
        canvas[imask] = img2[imask]
        
        dirname = "IMAGE_RESULTS_"+CURR_TIME
        
        Utils().make_dir(PATH, dirname)
        print("image where?")
        cv2.imwrite(dirname+"/result"+CURR_TIME+"_"+image_name+".png", canvas)
```

The `cv2.imwrite(dirname+"/result"+CURR_TIME+"_"+image_name+".png", canvas)` line is what I use to create the image.  The tkinter code is as follows:

```
def run_image_analysis():
    run_image_analysis.main().  

button1 = Button(root,text="run image analysis",command= run_image_analysis)
button1.pack()
```

The code for the make_dir function is here:

```
def make_dir(self, dirname, parent_dir):  
        path = os.path.join(parent_dir, dirname) 
        os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)
```

By playing around I found that running :

```
        cv2.imwrite(result"+CURR_TIME+"_"+image_name+".png", canvas)
```

actually works with tkinter. So apparently the new directory "dirname" referred to in the original code is not being created by makedir.  What exactly is going on here?  What confuses me is it works when I run it normally but not when I run it through tkinter.

Comment: Isn’t this a duplicate of a question you’ve already asked?

Comment: `make_dir` joins PATH and dirname but you only use dirname in imwrite.

Answer (score 0):

`make_dir` joins two path components to create a path for `mkdirs`. This method should return its constructed path to be used by the rest of the program.

```
def make_dir(self, dirname, parent_dir):  
        path = os.path.join(parent_dir, dirname) 
        os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True) 
        return path
```

Then change the callers

```
def compareImages(self,img1, img2, image_name):
        diff = cv2.absdiff(img1, img2)
        mask = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        th = 1
        imask =  mask>th
    
        canvas = np.zeros_like(img2, np.uint8)
        canvas[imask] = img2[imask]
        
        dirname = "IMAGE_RESULTS_"+CURR_TIME
        
        target_dir = Utils().make_dir(PATH, dirname)
        print("image where?")
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(target_dir, "/result"+CURR_TIME+"_"+image_name+".png"),
                canvas)
```

Comment: I'm not sure. The code doesn't say what PATH is - if its an empty string then then `dirname` would work. E.g., `os.path.join("foo", "")` is just `"foo/"`, the original directory.

Comment: I figured it out!  I had switched variable names when I passed them into the make_dirs function. Thanks for the help

Comment: I was wondering about that. I use vague names like and have made the same mistake. More descriptive variable names reduce the problem, but the brevity of short names is good too.